# Help with Level of Detail coding

Tags: python, mesh, game-engine, modifiers

I am creating this fps game in the bge and since I was planning on having incredibly large terrain, I was planning on implementing some code for adding level of detail to the terrain mesh. I know people usually just replace the mesh with a premodeled mesh with fewer polygonsbut my issue is adding different lods on the same mesh. I was thinking of assigning a vertex group to the mesh based around the players location and using code to move the vertex group when the player moves and anything outside the vertex group would have a decimate modifier. However I am not sure how practical this is. Are there better, faster ways to do this? Thanx in advance for the answers.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this on an object by object basis quite easily, there is a built in feature specifically for Level Of Detail configuration. Under the *Object* tab in the *Properties* panel, you will see a Level of Detail menu. Click *Add*, then select the mesh you want from the dropdown and set the distance you want it to become visible at.

[image: Level Of Detail]

Comment: and Now you are crossing X-27 territory